# Comparing value in a JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, python-requests

I receive a fairly uncomfortable JSON to work with, which looks as follows:

```
[
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "type": "COMMAND",
            "name": "COMMAND",
            "value": [
                "buttonState"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "std_msgs.msg.Bool",
            "name": "buttonState",
            "value": {
                "data": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "sensor",
    "id": "s_2"
}]
```

And I would like to compare a piece of data (more precisely - value of Button state) but I seem to fail. Tried following:

```
import requests
import json
yo = 1
switchPost = "http://192.168.0.104:7896/iot/d?k=123456789&i=san_1_switch&d=sw|{}"
robGet = "http://192.168.0.109:10100/robot/sen_2"

r = requests.get(robGet, headers={"content-type":"application/json"})
resp = json.loads(r.text)

for attrs in (resp['attributes']['value']):
    if attrs['data'] == false:
        yo = 100
        break
    
g = requests.post(switchPost.format(yo), headers={"content-type":"text/plain"})
print(r.text)
```

Unfortunately, the error I receive is the following:

> for attrs in (resp['attributes']['value']):
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Note how your values inside of `attributes` are additionally wrapped in a list; simply accessing it with an additional `[0]` should do the trick, i.e.
`resp['attributes'][0]['value']`

Comment: Note that the same might be necessary for the outer element as well, since there is a global list wrapper as well.

Comment: @dennlinger Thanks, I will take the following into consideration next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, the fact that it is wrapped in `[` then `]` means it is a JSON *array*, but with just one element.

So, as your error message suggests, `resp` needs an integer as its index, for which element of the array you want. `resp[0]` then refers to

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "type": "COMMAND",
            "name": "COMMAND",
            "value": [
                "buttonState"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "std_msgs.msg.Bool",
            "name": "buttonState",
            "value": {
                "data": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "sensor",
    "id": "s_2"
}
```

(notice no `[]` now, so it's a JSON *object*)

Then you want `resp[0]['attributes']` to refer to the single part of this object, `'attributes'` which again refers to an array.

Therefore `for attribute in resp[0]['attributes']` will allow you to loop through this array.

To get the boolean value you want, you'll then want to find which element of that array has `'name'` of `'buttonState'` and check the corresponding `'value'`.

In all, you're probably looking for something like:

```
for attribute in resp[0]['attributes']:
    if attribute['name'] == 'buttonState' and attribute['value']['data'] is False:
        # Do your thing here
```

Comment: So it was an array initially, that's why it needed an index to refer to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`resp` is a list so, to get first element, access it as `resp[0]`. Same with resp[0]['attributes']

So you can access it as follows

```
resp[0]['attributes'][0]['value']
```

You can restructure your for loop as follows

```
for d in resp[0]['attributes']:
    if isinstance(d['value'], dict) and d['value'].get('data') == false:
        yo = 100
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message I think:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

The first entry in `attributes` has a `value` that is a list, so you can't get 'data' from that. 
Since you have a mix of types, you might need to check if 'value' is a list or a dict.

Edit:
Jumped the gun here I think. @dennlinger gives an explanation to your error message. But you'll get it again once you're past that...